# Java.Error with telegram bot. Why don't I receive reminders?

Tags: java, spring, telegram-bot, reminders

Can you help me please? I am writing a telegram bot that will send a reminder about the start of the lecture at the university five minutes before the start of the lecture. This is the logic that should be: when a user writes his group, I make a request to the API `https://nure-dev.pp.ua/api/groups` to get the group identifier, then using this group I get the identifier (groupId), which should go to `https://nure-dev.pp.ua/api/schedule?type=group&id= + groupId + &start_time=1695365795&end_time=1695408995` and then follow the full API link `https://nure-dev.pp. ua/api/schedule?type=group&id= + groupId + &start_time=1695365795&end_time=1695408995` and then from this API you will receive a schedule and logic with a reminder. I use Spring Boot.

Example:

> /start
> Hello, Vlad! This telegram bot will notify you about the beginning of the lecture. To find out more, write /all
> /all
> everything you need
> /setgroup
> Enter your group (Example: KNT-23-3)
> KNT-23-3
> Group successfully installed: KNT-23-3
> /remind

And this tag `/remind` doesn't work. I don't receive reminders about the start of the lecture in five minutes. What should I do?

My base code:

```
    `class UniversityApiService`
```

```
@Component
public class UniversityApiService {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private static final String GROUPS_API_URL = "https://nure-dev.pp.ua/api/groups";
    private static final String TIME_PARAMETERS = "&start_time=1695365795&end_time=1697621662";
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public UniversityApiService(RestTemplate restTemplate, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.objectMapper=objectMapper;
    }

    public List<UniversityGroup> getGroups() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

        ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity;
        try {
            responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                    GROUPS_API_URL,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    entity,
                    String.class  // Change the response type to String
            );
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            MediaType contentType = e.getResponseHeaders().getContentType();
            if (contentType != null) {
                System.out.println("Response Content Type: " + contentType.toString());
            }

            if (contentType != null && contentType.includes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                // Handle plain text response
                String plainTextResponse = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
                try {
                    // Use ObjectMapper to deserialize the plain text response into a list of UniversityGroup objects
                    List<UniversityGroup> universityGroups = objectMapper.readValue(plainTextResponse, new TypeReference<List<UniversityGroup>>() {});
                    return universityGroups;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Handle deserialization error
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    return Collections.emptyList();
                }
            } else {
                // Handle other exceptions
                throw e;
            }
        }

        // can also add a check for JSON content type here and parse it accordingly
        // 

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    public String getGroupIdByName(String groupName) {
        List<UniversityGroup> groups = getGroups();

        if (groups != null) {
            for (UniversityGroup group : groups) {
                if (group.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(groupName)) {
                    return group.getId();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }


    public UniversitySchedule getNextLectureForGroup(String groupId) {
        ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity;
        try {
            responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                    "https://nure-dev.pp.ua/api/schedule?type=group&id=" + groupId + TIME_PARAMETERS,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    null,
                    String.class  // Change the response type to String
            );
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            MediaType contentType = e.getResponseHeaders().getContentType();
            if (contentType != null) {
                System.out.println("Response Content Type: " + contentType.toString());
            }

            if (contentType != null && contentType.includes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                // Handle plain text response
                String plainTextResponse = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
                try {
                    // Use ObjectMapper to deserialize the plain text response into a UniversitySchedule object
                    UniversitySchedule universitySchedule = objectMapper.readValue(plainTextResponse, UniversitySchedule.class);
                    return universitySchedule;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Handle deserialization error
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // Handle other exceptions
                throw e;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

```
 `class TelegramBot`
```

```
@Component
public class TelegramBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    private final BotConfig config;
    private String userGroup;

    private final ChatIdHolder chatIdHolder;
    private final UniversityApiService universityApiService;

    @Autowired
    public TelegramBot(BotConfig config, UniversityApiService universityApiService, ChatIdHolder chatIdHolder){
        this.config=config;
        this.universityApiService= universityApiService;
        this.chatIdHolder=chatIdHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return config.getBotName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return config.getToken();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()){
          String messageText = update.getMessage().getText();
          long chatId= update.getMessage().getChatId();
            chatIdHolder.setChatId(chatId);

           if (messageText.startsWith("/start")){
               startCommandReceived(chatId,update.getMessage().getChat().getFirstName());
            }else if(messageText.startsWith("/all")){
               startAllCommands(chatId);
           }else if(messageText.startsWith("/setgroup")){
               sendMessage(chatId, "Введіть вашу группу (Приклад: КНТ-23-3) ");

           }else if(messageText.startsWith("/remind")){
               if (userGroup != null) {
                   processUserGroup(userGroup);
               } else {
                   sendMessage(chatId, "Спочатку встановіть групу, використовуючи /setgroup.");
               }
           }else if (countCapitalLetters(messageText) < 2){
               sendMessage(chatId, "Вибачте, я не відповідаю на такі питання. Будь ласка, ознайомтеся з /all");
           }else if (countCapitalLetters(messageText) > 2) { // More than two capital letters
               sendMessage(chatId, "Група успішно установлена: " + messageText);
               userGroup = messageText; // Update userGroup
           }

        }

    }
    private int countCapitalLetters(String text) {
        int count = 0;
        for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    //настройка отправки сообщений
    private void sendMessage(long chatId, String textToSend){
        SendMessage message=new SendMessage();
        message.setChatId(String.valueOf(chatId));
        message.setText(textToSend);

        try{
            execute(message);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    public void sendLectureReminder(long chatId,String remiderText){
        SendMessage message2= new SendMessage();
        message2.setChatId(String.valueOf(chatId));
        message2.setText(remiderText);
    }

    public void processUserGroup(String groupName) {
        // Step 1: Get the group ID by group name
        String groupId = universityApiService.getGroupIdByName(groupName);

        if (groupId != null) {
            // Step 2: Get the next lecture for the group
            UniversitySchedule nextLecture = universityApiService.getNextLectureForGroup(groupId);

            if (nextLecture != null) {
                // Step 3: Calculate the reminder time (5 minutes before the lecture)
                long lectureStartTime = nextLecture.getStart_time();
                long reminderTime = lectureStartTime - (5 * 60);

                // Step 4: Convert the reminder time to a human-readable format (if needed)
                String reminderTimeFormatted = unixTimestampToDateTime(reminderTime);

                // Step 5: Create the reminder text
                String reminderText = "Your next lecture is at " + reminderTimeFormatted +
                        ". Lecture: " + nextLecture.getSubject().getTitle();

                // Step 6: Send the reminder
                long chatId = chatIdHolder.getChatId();
                sendLectureReminder(chatId, reminderText);
            }
        }
    }

    private String unixTimestampToDateTime(long unixTimestamp) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = new Date(unixTimestamp * 1000);
            return dateFormat.format(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void startCommandReceived(long chatId, String name){

        String answer= "Привіт, " +name+ "! Цей телеграм бот буде сповіщати про початок лекцій.Щоб дізнатися більше напишіть /all ";
        sendMessage(chatId, answer);

    }

    private void startAllCommands(long chatId){
        String allCommands= "все що треба";
        sendMessage(chatId, allCommands);

    }

    public String getUserGroup(){
        return userGroup;
    }
    public void setUserGroup(String userGroup){

    }

}
```

`class ChatIdHolder`

```
@Component
@Data
public class ChatIdHolder {
    private long chatId;


}
```

`class UniversityGroup(UniversityScedule similare)`

```
@Data
public class UniversityGroup {

    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar which library/API you're using, but it seems you do not send your messages (method 'sendLectureReminder'). Also, I would recommend you to debug your code via debugger.